# Delete recycler items based on specific user preferences

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using android studio and fire base real time database  for my project. I have some customer enquires displayed in shops's activity using recycler view. When a shop accept that enquiry, I want that enquiry to be removed from his recycler view list (only for that user(shop), I don't want that to be removed from entire firebase database, so it will be available other users(shops),  But when I tried to remove the item from single shop user, it is getting deleted from my firebase data base. Whether any one can tell me how I can achieve my requirement .

Comment: Looks like a mix of business logic and implementation problem to me. Lets take a step back: If you need the data to be maintained please make sure you use some sort of flag that helps with soft delete than the real delete. Now imagining thats in place, you can control the visibility of the items in recycler view by handling the list of items being sent to it. Manage the list using LiveData or any other logic that you prefer, and that in turn will manage the list in view. Please have a look at LiveData and DiffUtil.ItemCallback approach which I think will be the best fit for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think u need create database for each user. Even if you can write logic to hide and show to each user without actually deleting it Imagine what happen if you have a lot of users. How can your logic remember which user and their activities? I'm not saying that u need to store all the list you gonna show to all users for each user, but rather only store items which users have deleted and then you can write your business logic to compare your original list with their deleted item and show them depend on that. (I can't comment since my reputation below 50) hope it is helpful.

Comment: logic is simple, If a customer have a requirement he will send to all  sellers.  This will be populated in recycler view of seller home page. This type of requirements should be available to all users who registered as sellers. If one seller express interest to a particular customer requirement he has to press express interest button, once he press  that button that particular requirement has to move from his main activity to offer fragment  (only for that seller who pressed the button, for other sellers it should still be there itself). If you cant comment please  answer

Comment: when the sellers press button, add the item requirement to `database` and navigate to `fragment` with that item and write a logic to compare your original list with his list (database) and remove duplication item and show a new list without duplicate item to him. U can use `livedata`, `mutablestate` for your list, or recall your `recyclerview` after he pressed so that u can update the list.

Comment: @ jorieitomuke I understand your logic , but if a seller press the button and express interest,  I have to remove that inquiry from that the recycler list in enguiry fragment to offers fragment, when I tried to do so,  the item is getting removed from the database and then it will not be available for other sellers. I want that item (requirement) to be visible for other sellers, I want that requirement to available to other sellers as well so that they can put their offer

Comment: How to hide details in recycler view for a specific user..  are you telling to reduce the length of view to zero ??